# What does the parenthesis around a use flag means?

Tags: curl, gentoo, options

I want to build my curl with the **quiche** support. I have enabled the use flag in the package.use file, but it does not take effect. I noticed there are a pair of parenthesis around the use flag. What does it mean?

```
[ebuild   R    ] net-misc/curl-7.66.0::gentoo  USE="http2* ipv6 ldap progress-meter samba ssl threads* -adns -alt-svc -brotli -idn -kerber
os -metalink (-nghttp3) (-quiche) -rtmp -ssh -static-libs -test" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" CURL_SSL="openssl -gnutls -libressl -mbedtls -n
ss (-winssl)" 0 KiB
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paranthesis indicate that the package supports that USE-flag but for some reason, you cannot change it's value with your current setup (profile, architecture, ...).
There's a pretty good reference about emerge's output here: http://wikigentoo.ksiezyc.pl/HOWTO_Use_Portage_Correctly.htm#USE_Flags